# What is a "tomato word"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases, pronunciation

In [this explanation](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/myopic) of the word `myopic` I get stuck by this sentence:

> In terms of pronunciation: it's a **tomato/tomahto word**: pronounce it
>   "my-OP-ick" or "my-OH-pick," although that short o sound is preferred.

Then what is a tomato word? I have searched everywhere but found no such a phrase. I thought may be because the o is pronounced the same as the o in tomato? But it seems really like a phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the whole phrase:  **a tomato/tomahto word**. In the USA, some people pronounce the word 'tomato' so that the 'a' vowel is said like the 'a' in plate, date, late, etc, and others pronounce it like the 'a' in the southern British pronunciation of father, past, last, etc, which is often represented in American writing as 'ah'. A tomayto/tomahto word is one where there are two possible pronunciations.

Comment: It is really a British English/American English division. I've never yet met a North American who says "tom-ah-to". Perhaps mid-Atlantic speakers from New England?

Comment: I always thought, like you, that the well-know song was based on a US/British pair of lovers who said certain words differently tomato, potato, either, etc, but I read somewhere that the difference was a class-based one among people in New England.

Comment: Yep the mid Atlantic accent of that period, which was a class based affectation of Englishness. But I think it is pretty much defunct. And the song is a bit tricksy anyway, because nobody ever said "potahto" anywhere.

Comment: I think the potahto was partly a joke and partly because there aren't a lot of rhymes for tomahto. I suppose there's pizzicato or gelato but too many foreign words might have frightened the horses.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If I ever hear anybody offer me a *ge-lay-to*, I'll run away, scared. ;)

Comment: It's the sort of thing you hear British tourists say in Italy.

Comment: @fred2 - My mother, who grew up in Boston (and yes, went to a prep school), says "to-mah-to."